# What is the linguistic name of [r͡ʙ]?

Tags: terminology, phonetics, coarticulation

I am creating a language with the sound [r͡ʙ].

The only name I can come up for this sound would be a simultaneous bilabial and alveolar trill.

Is there anything more scientific than that?

It cannot occur after /s/, /k/, or /ts/

Comment: Is this a phoneme by itself or an allophone of another phoneme? What are the limitations of whatever phoneme it belongs to? Like, can it occur doubled? Can it occur after /s/? How about after /k/? Before /ts/? Etc.

Comment: call it an apico-alveolar bilabial trill. by analogy, [kp] is called a voiceless labial velar stop. also, you don't care whether it is aerodynamically possible, do you?